# How can i re write the null checking line since it's not supporting in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\mysvg\Documents\my.svg");
            XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

            var list = document.Root.Descendants(ns + "rect").Select(e => new {
                Style = e.Attribute("style").Value.Substring(15, 7),
                Transform = e.Attribute("transform")?.Value,
                Width = e.Attribute("width").Value,
                Height = e.Attribute("height").Value,
                X = e.Attribute("x").Value
            });
```

In csharp it's working fine.
But in unity visual studio i'm getting error on the line:

```
e.Attribute("transform")?.Value.Substring(18, 43)
```

Feature 'null propagating operator' is not available in C# 4.  Please use language version 6 or greater.

In csharp i didn't have to change anything.

The visual studio i'm using in unity (same as for csharp) is: 14.0.24531.01 Update 3 and visual c# 2015

Maybe i need to change the line checking for null for something else ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with VS, but rather the C# compiler that is used in Unity - which as the error states only supports up to C# 4.0. So you have to write "old-style" null-checks, e.g.: `if(e.Attribute("transform") != null)`

Comment: @UnholySheep but where and how do i add this old null checking ? I changed the line to it's original: Transform = e.Attribute("transform").Value.Substring(18, 43) but now where to add the if(e.Attribute("transform") != null) i can't just add the line above the e.Attribute line.

Comment: You put that inside the if statement. Are you still struggling with this?

Comment: @Programmer yes still didn't understand where/how to put the if(e.Attribute("transform") != null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know why you can't use `?.` and that's because Unity does not support that version of C# that supports `?.`.

[UnholySheep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2878796/unholysheep) comment suggests using if statement but I don't think you can use that here.

You can check for `null` with the ternary operator.

Use:

```
Transform = e.Attribute("transform") != null ? e.Attribute("transform").Value : "",
```

If you are still confused. Here is the whole code:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\mysvg\Documents\my.svg");
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

var list = document.Root.Descendants(ns + "rect").Select(e => new
{
    Style = e.Attribute("style").Value.Substring(15, 7),
    Transform = e.Attribute("transform") != null ? e.Attribute("transform").Value : "",
    Width = e.Attribute("width").Value,
    Height = e.Attribute("height").Value,
    X = e.Attribute("x").Value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the old fashioned way with a ternary operator `?:`, and I'd get the attribute outside the collection initializer so you don't have to index it twice:

```
var list = document.Root.Descendants(ns + "rect").Select(e => 
    var tr = e.Attribute("transform");

    new {Style = e.Attribute("style").Value.Substring(15, 7),
    Transform = (tr != null) ? tr.Value : null,
    Width = e.Attribute("width").Value,
    Height = e.Attribute("height").Value,
    X = e.Attribute("x").Value
});
```

If you upgrade your version of Visual Studio to 2015 or 2017, you can use the null conditional operator.

Comment: No, upgrading the Visual Studio version will not enable the usage of C# 6 in Unity - it has it's own compiler which currently does not support C# 6 (though it is planned for future versions when the Mono Runtime gets upgraded)

Comment: It's not working. You can't add var before the new { it's giving many errors.